# What data structure to use for digraph paths?

Tags: algorithm, database-design, data-structures

I'm trying to represent a transitive relation (in a database) and having a hard time working out the best data structure.

Basically, the data structure is a series of pairs `A → B` such that if `A → B` and `B → C`, then implicitly `A → C`. It's important to me to be able to identify which entries are original input and which entries exist implicitly. Asking if `A → C` is equivalent to me having a digraph and asking if there exists a path from `A` to `C` in that digraph.

I could just represent the original entries, but if I do than then it takes a lot of time to determine if two items are related, since I need to search for all possible paths and this is rather slow.

Alternatively, I can store the original edges, as well as a listing of all paths. This makes adding a new edge easy, because when I add `A → B` I can just take the Cartesian product of paths ending in `A` and the paths ending in `B` and put them together. This has some significant space overhead of O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) in the worst case, but has the nice property that lookups, by far the most common operation, will be constant time. The issue is deleting, where I cannot think of anything really other than recalculating all paths that may or may not run through the edge deleted, and this can be really nasty.

Does anyone have any better ideas?

Technical notes: the digraph may be cyclic, but the relation is reflexive so I don't need to represent the reflexivity or store anything about it.

Comment: @rici, coppro said that the relation is [reflexive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_relation), not reflective (by which, based on your comment, I think you mean [symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation)).  That means that each node is related to itself.  In terms of the graph, it means that for each vertex _v_, there's an edge _v → v_.

Comment: I don't know offhand what data structure you should use, but the following observation might help in searching.  Your input (the set of pairs) is a relation _R_.  You're looking for the reflexive transitive _closure_ of _R_.  If you call the equality or diagonal relation =, then you're looking for the transitive closure of = ∪ _R_.  Now you can search for data structures for transitive closures that support efficient edge deletion.

Comment: This may not be an answer but a suggestion. Do you mind working with a graph database?

Comment: Depending on what you need to do, @TharinduRusira's suggestion of a graph database might be overkill, but I agree that what you're trying to do would be pretty easy using an RDF triple store and SPARQL 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [**Reachability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability) problem.

It would seem that you want an efficient online algorithm, which is an open problem, and an area of much research.

See my similar question on [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com): [**An incrementally-condensed transitive-reduction of a DAG, with efficient reachability queries**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14798/2755), where I reference several related querstions across stackexchange:

> #### Related:
>
> - [What is the fastest deterministic algorithm for dynamic digraph reachability with no edge deletion?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14343/3377)
> - [What is the fastest deterministic algorithm for incremental DAG reachability?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18787/3377)
> - [Does an algorithm exist to efficiently maintain connectedness information for a DAG in presence of inserts/deletes?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/5176/3377)
> - [Is there an online-algorithm to keep track of components in a changing undirected graph?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2548/3377)
> - [Dynamic shortest path data structure for DAG](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/17135/3377)

Note that even though some algorithm might be for a DAG only, if it supports [*condensation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation_(graph_theory)) (that is, collapsing strongly connected components into one node, since they are considered equal, ie. they relate back and forth), it is equivalent; after condensation, you can query the graph for the representative node in place of any of the condensed nodes (because they were both reachable from each-other, and thusly related to the rest of the graph in exactly the same way).

My conclusion is that as-of-yet there does not seem to be an efficient way to do this (on the order of O(log n) queries for a dynamic graph, with output-sensitive update times on the condensed graph). For less efficient ways, see the related links above.

The closest practical algorithm I found was [here](http://code-o-matic.blogspot.com/2010/07/graph-reachability-transitive-closures.html) ([source](http://code.google.com/p/transitivity-utils)), which is an interesting read. I am not sure how easy/practical this data-structure or *any* data structure in any paper you will find, would be to adapt it to a database.

PS. Consider asking CS-related questions on [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) in the future.